# Docker Image `httpd` with libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Tags: django, apache, docker, apache2

I'm currently creating a Dockerfile with a base image httpd:2 And I manually installed libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 is there a way I can use mod-wsgi for my Django Application to another container?

Comment: I enter the container and the default location for the modules are in the **/usr/local/apache2/modules** but when I installed mod-wsgi it was installed on **/etc/apache2/mods-available**